# Am I banned from Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, gis

I have created a GIS application that builds the URL for a Google Static Map.

(example: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=32.3077562448,36.3423937253&zoom=18&size=1280x1280&scale=2&maptype=satellite&sensor=false).

This application was working perfectly until this morning, when all these URLs started to show the following image.

[image: quota]

Has Google banned my IP adress? If yes, how long will the ban last?

Answer (score 2):

You should read the [Google Static Maps Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Limits)

> The Google Static Maps API has the following usage limits:
>
> ```
> 25 000 free static map requests per application per 24 hour period.
> ```
>
> Additional image requests can be purchased on a per application basis
>   at the rate currently listed in the FAQ. Additional quota is purchased
>   through the API Console and requires the use of an API key.
>
> If a user exceeds these limits, the server will return an HTTP 403
>   status and display the below image to indicate that the quota has been
>   exceeded:

25 000 requests per day does not seem to be the only limit though. It seems that google does deny access if requests per 15 minutes exceed some 100 or so for a single IP Address. The image you see obviously is a result of these limitations. Usually the limit will be reset soon (after 15 to 60 Minutes).

Comment: That's right, I have probably exceeded 100 requests in 15 minutes. And I confirm that one hour later I had access again to the service. Thanks!